# include content from html files into one main html file and then download it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to create a page in which I have some checkboxes like: 
Add headers:

"Add header-1",  "Add header-2"  "Add header-3"

Add contents:

"Add content-1",  "Add content-2"  "Add content-3"

and the same for "footers"

For each one of these checkboxes corresponds an html file, for example "header-1" corresponds to a file on my server called "header-1.html"  and the same for the other files.

What I want to do is adding a button called "Download" and  after the user checks, let's say "add header-1" and "add-content-1" and click "Download" they will receive an archive with the selected files merged into one main file called "index.html" .

This is an overall view about what I'm trying to achieve.

Is this possible using PHP ? If so can you give me some suggestions from where can I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do, is use `file_get_contents()` on each of the files that have been selected, and then just concatenate those strings together. You'd  have to come up with a way to determine which file has been selected, but then you'd just replace the file names with variables.

```
$fileOne = file_get_contents(file1.html);
$fileTwo = file_get_contents(file2.html);
$fileThree = file_get_contents(file3.html);

$fileToDownload = $fileOne.$fileTwo.$fileThree;
```

Then write the file :

```
$rHandler = fopen('my-new-file.html', r+);
fwrite($rHandler, $fileToDownlod);
fclose($rHandler);
```

Then just provide a link to whereever you wrote the HTML file.

```
<a href='my-new-file.html'>Download here</a>
```

UPDATE

You wanted to offer a zip file. Taken from http://php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php

```
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "./my-html-files.zip";

if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}

$zip->addFromString("testfilephp.txt" . time(), "#1 This is a test string added as      testfilephp.txt.\n");
$zip->addFromString("testfilephp2.txt" . time(), "#2 This is a test string added as testfilephp2.txt.\n");
$zip->addFile($thisdir . "/too.php","/testfromfile.php");
echo "numfiles: " . $zip->numFiles . "\n";
echo "status:" . $zip->status . "\n";
$zip->close();
?>
```

Then just offer a new download link

```
<a href='my-html-file.zip'>Download here</a>
```